CMake not linking to SUNDIALS targets. Why is CMake unable to find the SUNDIALS libraries?
I am trying to build pion using a CMake style build system. The only problem is the grid simulation modules(pion-ng,pion-ug,icgen-ng,icgen-ug) are unable to link to the SUNDIALS(VER 7.1.1) functions although CMake(VER 3.2.2.1) correctly does find my SUNDIALS installation but doesn't link to it.
In the CMakeLists.txt file at /pion/ I use find_package(SUNDIALS REQUIRED) and set the -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to /sundials/install/ and add the flag  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I/mnt/e/sundials/install/include" (without explicitly adding this flag, CMake does not detect the header files).
My CMakeLists.txt file at /pion/source attempts to link like this:
    # pion-ng internal dependencies
    target_link_libraries(pion-ng PRIVATE
        nested_sim_control
        nested_grid
    SUNDIALS::cvode_shared
    SUNDIALS::nvecserial_shared
        SUNDIALS::sunmatrixdense_shared
        SUNDIALS::sunlinsoldense_shared
        SUNDIALS::sunnonlinsolnewton_shared
    )

    # icgen-ng internal dependencies
    target_link_libraries(icgen-ng PRIVATE
        ics
        nested_grid
    SUNDIALS::cvode_shared
    SUNDIALS::nvecserial_shared
        SUNDIALS::sunmatrixdense_shared
        SUNDIALS::sunlinsoldense_shared
        SUNDIALS::sunnonlinsolnewton_shared
    )

But I get this error when running  cmake -DSILO_INCLUDE_DIR=/mnt/e/pion/extra_libraries/include       -DSILO_LIBRARY=/mnt/e/pion/extra_libraries/lib/libsilo.so       -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/mnt/e/sundials/install       -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I/mnt/e/sundials/install/include" .. :

CMake Error at source/CMakeLists.txt:93 (add_executable):
Target "pion-ug" links to target "SUNDIALS::cvode_shared" but the target
was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

I have also added some lines for debugging after the find_package(SUNDIALS REQUIRED):
if (TARGET SUNDIALS::cvode_shared)
  message(STATUS "SUNDIALS::cvode target found")
else()
  message(STATUS "SUNDIALS::cvode target not found")
endif()

if (TARGET SUNDIALS::nvecserial_shared)
  message(STATUS "SUNDIALS::nvecserial target found")
else()
  message(STATUS "SUNDIALS::nvecserial target not found")
endif()

Both print "target not found".
Successfully build pion using a manual installation of SUNDIALS (not installed using a package manager) [I need the manual installation].

According to sources, prefix of the target created is sundials_nvecserial. So you need to use SUNDIALS::sundials_nvecserial_shared for access that target after find_package.

Didn't work, I tried rebuilding by changing the names to include the sundials_ prefix in both CMakeLists. It still says target not found when I write sundials_nvecserial_shared. My SUNDIALS installation is correct and upto date.
